# how to use different classes as an argument in a method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, generics, coding-style

I am going to explain my problem so clear I can :)

I use a webservice in a jar file. In this jar file there is different classes that I will use. Each class is for one year:

> - 2012 has a class with the name **Service12**.
> - 2013 has a class with the name **Service13**.
> - 2014 has a class with the name **service14**.

and so on.

These classes is just use-only and I cannot change anything in this jar-file.

I will use the classes regarding each year in a webService, but not with `if-else`, since it is more than 20 years service methods.:

```
public myObj methodA (int year){
    ServiceXX serviceXX = myWebService.useThisService(ServiceXX.class);
}
```

And **myWebService** has a generic method like this one:

```
public <T> T useThisService(Class<T> serviceClass) {        
    return (T) this.getService(serviceClass);
}
```

How can I code methodA so without any `if-else` I can user correct **ServiceXX** for each **year**.

Hope it is clear enough to get help.

Comment: you can create a `interface` and extend all your `classes` with that and then your can pass `interface` reference;

Comment: `switch` is a good alternative of `if-else`, however first comment is a better option.

Comment: @eatSleepCode : As I mentioned, I cannot do anything like that since the classes att use-only and is from the jar-file I use them.

Kishan Sarsecha Gajjar: switch and if-else is not realy what I will. This code can be more complex in future and I need a more stable code and less risk to refactor this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you use `myWebService.useThisService(Class.forName("Service" + year));` ?

Comment: Not actually ... The name can be changed in the future and don't follow todays pattern.

Comment: @Shari If you can "predict the future", then you can catch `ClassNotFoundException` and try with a different naming pattern. If you can't predict the future and you don't know which might be the next naming patterns, then either you can't do that today (Agile practitioners would probably tell it's not even worth) or you can plan ahead by adding more cleverness using a configuration file to configure the possible patterns and [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to generate the possible name

Comment: Thanks Raffaele. I have decided the agile mindset. Use the best solution for today and change it if needed in future.